# jQuery geocomplete output to custom fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, geocomplete

I have been trying to get it to map to fields i specify but have not had any luck. We have a form that we can not control the field names etc. and are trying to map the results to each field. Is it possible to map for say example the lat and long to fields that might be named like so

Lat input field name=ctl00$placeholderBody$ctl03$txtCustomField1

```
<input name="ctl00$placeholderBody$ctl03$txtCustomField1" type="text" id="ctl00_placeholderBody_ctl03_txtCustomField1">
```

Lon input field name=ctl00$placeholderBody$ctl03$txtCustomField2

```
<input name="ctl00$placeholderBody$ctl03$txtCustomField2" type="text" id="ctl00_placeholderBody_ctl03_txtCustomField2">
```

Here is an example but I do not see how to map the output to other custom field names. http://codepen.io/abennington/pen/dMgqRq

Any help and example code would be a life saver! :)

Comment: if it helps here is an example with the custom fields for lat and lng that i am not able to figure out how to get them to populate. http://codepen.io/abennington/pen/ONBBxW Also i can not change the field name or alter them since they are driven by a CMS.

Comment: Can you alter other attributes of the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Call Geo Complete
  $('#ctl00_placeholderBody_ctl03_txtCustomField1').attr('data-geo','lat');
  $('#ctl00_placeholderBody_ctl03_txtCustomField2').attr('data-geo','lng');
  $("#search").geocomplete({details:"form#property",map:"#map",detailsAttribute:'data-geo'});
});
```

I got this to work. In your example you had the same ID names, but just add a attribute (whatever you want the plugin uses data-geo as an example), but add the attribute and then set the geocomplete to reference that attribute for the data. See the Populate form data section of the plugin.

Basically the plugin as you noticed is looking for fields names lat and lng. The `detailsAttribute` option tells the plugin to look for something other than the name attribute.

Comment: If you can edit the form fields then just change `<input name="ctl00$placeholderBody$ctl03$txtCustomField1" type="text" id="ctl00_placeholderBody_ctl03_txtCustomField1">` to `<input name="ctl00$placeholderBody$ctl03$txtCustomField1" type="text" id="ctl00_placeholderBody_ctl03_txtCustomField1" data-geo="lat">` and the same for lng.

Comment: Wow! So the lat and lng now work but it is not filling in the other address fields.

Comment: since we changed the plugin to look for `data-geo` attribute you'll need to add `data-geo=locality` and others on the fields you want to populate. You can do it in the HTML if you want or if you can't edit those either do it via javascript. For instance `<input type="text" class="form-control" data-geo="locality" name="locality" id="city" placeholder="City">` or `$('#city').attr('data-geo','locality');`